# Laravel form input field set height and width

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I try to set width of input field in laravel 5. Anybody know why is it not working?

```
{!! Form::input('text','table_list', null, array('required'=>'required','width' => 100)) !!}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_width.asp):

> Note: The width attribute is used only with `<input type="image">`.

Meaning you will have to style your text inputs via css:

```
{!! Form::input('text','table_list', null, array('required'=>'required','class' => 'foo')) !!}
```

And then define the `.foo` class:

```
.foo {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use size parameter instead as in HTML [(see documentation)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp).
Make sure that the attribute is not overridden in the CSS afterwards.

```
{!! Form::input('text','table_list', null, array('required'=>'required','size' => 100)) !!}
```