# not able to give the size (width ) of textfield in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('quantity','Quantity(Numbers of decks)')}}
        {{Form::text('quantity','Enter quantity',['class' => 
        'form-control'])}}
</div>
```

not able to give the size (width ) of textfield in laravel
 i want to give the size or with of the textfield in this code and not in external file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel form input field set height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376238/laravel-form-input-field-set-height-and-width)

Comment: You should know that inline CSS is considered a bad practice among many developers. You might want to write it in an external file first and use a closure compiler later.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('quantity','Quantity(Numbers of decks)')}}
    {{Form::text('quantity','Enter quantity',['class' => 
    'form-control','style'=>'width:x px'])}}
```